# Converting String to Object using ObjectMapper but ignore field with @JsonIgnore property

Tags: java, jackson, marshalling, unmarshalling, objectmapper

User class:

```
@Data
class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I have the scenario where I have to write user object as string, but I don't want 'id' field to be included in it for which I have used @JsonIgnore property
I am using objectMapper to write the value as String:

```
String s = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user);
```

This creates String value as expected (exluding id field).

But at next step I required the object from String s(But it should not have id field - But when I am trying to do it using readValue, I am getting the id field in the object with default value - which I do not want.)

```
User value = mapper.readValue(s, User.class);
```

Below is the whole code:

```
@Data
class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

public class Test {
    ObjectMapper objMapper;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.meth();
    }

    public void meth() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(2);
        user.setName("Bob");
        System.out.println(user);
        String s = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(user);
        User value = mapper.readValue(s, User.class);
        System.out.println("==>String Value:\n" + s);
        System.out.println("===>Object Value:\n" + value);
    }
}
```

Output I am getting:

```
==>String Value:
{
  "name" : "Bob"
}
===>Object Value:
User(id=0, name=Bob)
```

Expected output:

```
==>String Value:
{
  "name" : "Bob"
}
===>Object Value:
User(name=Bob)
```

Please see Object Value in both Actual and Expected output.

Looking forward to a simple solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int` can’t be null, for that you would at least need an `Integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` can't be `null` since it's a primitive datatype. You can use `Integer` because it's an object and therefore can be `null`.

I think then you still have to tell json that it can ignore fields that are not in the json with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

---

When you're goal is to just get the output without the id when you print the user you can override the `toString` method:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User(name=" + name + ")";
}
```

Or since you use the `Data` annotation which contains the `ToString` annotation you can add `@ToString.Exclude` over your id field

Comment: I have taken id as Integer and also included @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) at class level.  Now the output I am getting is:


===>Object Value:
User(id=null, name=Bob)

How to achieve the expected output?

Please help.

Comment: If you don't want the id on User remove it.

Comment: Or if you just want the id not to show when you print it in console override the toString method.

Comment: I want id for my logic, but don't want to display it in logger.

Comment: In that case override toString. I edited my answer

Comment: I don't want it in object. Check the question, when I am writing it as String, it is ignoring id, but not ignoring id when I am creating object from that String.

Comment: You just said you don't want the id to show up in logs and before that you wanted to achieve  the expected output that's what I just gave you the solution for. Despite that it's ignored for this the `JsonIgnore` annotation is responsible and that's why it's `null` ;)

Comment: yes, I get that. But I want object to be logged, not the string.

Comment: Nothing different happens right now. You just don't see it. Take a look at the `Data` annotation. https://projectlombok.org/features/Data - It contains the ToString annotation which results in your current toString representation of the object because it generates the toString method. Normal object representation without overriden toString in System.out.println looks something like this: Object@3f91beef.

Comment: I guess I was able to help you and explain this matter to you. So I would appreciate when you accept this answer. You're welcome^^ Have a nice day :)

Comment: Yes sure. However, my issue was not resolved, but you helped to an extent, so thank you for that :)